Sync outlook calendar to sharepoint list
I'm new to power automate and flows. I am trying to sync my outlook calendar to sharepount list using flow. I did try using "get calendar" but it only adds items to my list if I add a new event. What I want is I want my entire calendar in sharepoint. So is there some way to do this?
In the end, it doesn't matter which way you do it, but all I want is my calendar inside sharepoint. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
I tried to embed calendar, but I can only embed a single calendar. I have like 2 to 3 team members. So I want all their calendars together in one single calendar. So that is why I tried with flow.
